# python -m pip install pyspectator

Tags: windows, windows-10, python

```
Ввожу

python -m pip install pyspectator

Выводит ошибку

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Topovyu Komp\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-c84w2xp4\\pyspectator\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Topovyu Komp\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-c84w2xp4\\pyspectator\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\Topovyu Komp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-c84w2xp4\pyspectator\pip-egg-info'
         cwd: C:\Users\Topovyu Komp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-c84w2xp4\pyspectator\
    Complete output (1 lines):
    error in pyspectator setup command: 'install_requires' must be a string or list of strings containing valid project/version requirement specifiers; Invalid requirement, parse error at "'-r base.'"
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

как мне установить pyinstaller
```

Answer (score 0):

**pyspectator**

> Выводит ошибку

As indicated in this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/it-geeks-club/pyspectator/issues/23), you need to modify `windows.txt` in the source files for `pyspectator`:

1. Download [pyspectator-1.2.1.tar.gz](https://pypi.org/project/pyspectator/#files) from PyPI (this is where `pip` downloads `pyspectator` from normally).
2. Extract `pyspectator-1.2.1.tar.gz` with a program such as [7-zip](https://www.7-zip.org/).
3. Under the `pyspectator-1.2.1\requirements` folder, there should be two files:

   - `base.txt`
   - `windows.txt`

   *ex. pyspectator-1.2.1\requirements*

   [image: pyspectator-1.2.1requirements folder - screenshot]
4. Open `windows.txt`. Remove the very first line (i.e. `-r base.txt`). Then open `base.txt` and copy the contents of `base.txt` to `windows.txt`. Save `windows.txt` once you are finished.

   *ex. windows.txt*

   ```
   psutil>=2.1.1
   netifaces>=0.10.4
   pyvalid>=0.9
   pytest>=2.6.2
   enum34>=1.0
   wmi>=1.4.9
   ```
5. From the ex. `pyspectator-1.2.1` folder, run e.g. `python setup.py install` from the command line.

   *ex. python setup.py install*

   [image: python setup.py install command line - screenshot]

   *ex. setup.py*

   [image: pyspectator-1.2.1 setup.py location - screenshot]

**PyInstaller**

> как мне установить pyinstaller

[PyInstaller does not officially support Python 3.8](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/4265) at the time of this writing. So you will to install this [development version](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/archive/develop.tar.gz) if you want support for Python 3.8. You can install this version directly with e.g.:

```
python -m pip install https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/archive/develop.tar.gz
```

Otherwise, `PyInstaller` will likely crash when compiling your script on Python 3.8 (at the `Building PYZ (ZArchiveLib)` step).

---

**Notes**

- On Windows, `pyspectator` may require you to install [pywin32](https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/) (e.g. `python -m pip install pywin32`) to run certain functions.
- `pyspectator` is built from scratch by Python. Therefore, you may need to install ex. *Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools* beforehand (so the `pyspectator` module can be compiled).
- You may want consider using Python 3.7 rather than Python 3.8. Anecdotally, when compiling a `pyspectator` script into an executable with the Python 3.8 versions of the modules above, I ran into a `.dll not found` issue which seemed resolved when using Python 3.7 instead.
- As a recommended installation order, I would suggest:

  1. *pywin32*
  2. *pyspectator*
  3. *PyInstaller*